# Is there any requirement to use for restore button in auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, payment, storekit

I realize that applications which are includes in-app purchases require restore button to prompt user.

But non-consumable items not included. Is it necessary on  Auto-renawable items ?

if it so,  I'm very curious about where I must to put the restore button  it would be killing my design.

Comment: It isn't required but it is highly recommended. It provides an easy way for users to re-activate their subscription on another or a new device.  You would normally have the restore button in your "store" interface.

Comment: it is highly recommended I accept that. But some people says if you wouldn't use restore button apple will be rejected. If it is not mandatory then no need to put that in to my application. I assume you understand me clearly.

Comment: The only way to know what Apple will approve is to submit your app. The review guidelines tell you some things they won't approve. Personally I think the restore button is a very useful feature. If you aren't going to have one then ensure you test installing your app on another device or an erased device and that the subscription is activated on that device correctly.

Comment: Also, your question has it the wrong way around; consumable IAPs cannot be restored.  Non-consumable and auto renewing subscriptions can be.

Comment: oh sorry yeah you are right. I was try to mean that consumables.

Comment: You must provide a mechanism to restore - it doesn't have to be a restore button. So if you have a bulletproof authentication mechanism you could restore purchases through that. Netflix doesn't have a restore button, but they probably have 1000 engineers working on auth.

Comment: Yeah ı think so. I understand to reason why its complicated problem if you cant provide a restore mechanism you need to add restore button into your application otherwise apple would be reject your item. Hopefully I undertand correctly in that case I have to implement restore button.